# NSNotification to detect other program's crashes

Tags: cocoa, macos, crash, launchd, nsnotification

I was planning on writing a small daemon that detected whether another app crashed, thinking all the while that the system would send an **NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification**, but this is not the case.

Assuming that I do not want to create a launchd process to simply re-launch the crashed application, can I detect the crash any other way?

Perhaps I could monitor the system log? That seems unduly burdensome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what worked best as a crash monitor was reading the FSEventStream for Crash Logs.

Answer (score 1):

How about watching for if/when the `/usr/sbin/spindump` process starts up?

Comment: Interesting - I didn't think about that. I'll report back soon.